# Excel is not opening csv file when index=False option is selected in to_csv command

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

Hi I can export and open the csv file in windows if I do:

`y.to_csv('sample.csv')`.

where y is a pandas dataframe.

However, this output file has an index column. I am able to export the output file to csv by doing:

`y.to_csv('sample.csv',index=False)`

But when I try to open the file is showing an error message:

"The file format and extension of 'sample.csv' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust it's source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?"

Sample of y:

[image]

Comment: can you print a sample of the dataframe `y`?

Comment: Hi briancaffey, dataframe k is same as y and I am facing the same issue with dataframe k as well.

Comment: What if you click Yes when it asks "Do you want to open it anyway?"?

Comment: The csv file opens but the dataframe inside it is missing even though file size in 55mb.

Comment: Please confirm using anything other than Excel (any command-line tool or editor) that the file is actually empty, not that Excel is hiding the column? If the filesize is 55MB it ain't empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the name of the `ID` column. That's a special name that Excel recognizes. If the first cell of the first column of a CSV is `ID`, Excel will try to interpret the file as another file type. Since when you don't exclude the index, the ID column appears in the second column, it's fine. But when you exclude the index column, `ID` appears in the first cell of the first column, and Excel gets confused. You can either change the name of the column, keep the index column, or change the order of the columns in the data frame so that the `ID` column doesn't appear first.

Comment: Excellent it works now. I just renamed the 'ID' column.

Comment: @MadhukarJha: then the issue was different to what the question claimed. Can you please fix the question?

Comment: I have modified the question to better reflect the issue. If you have better heading then let me know. I will change accordingly so that others can benefit too.

Comment: Furthermore, I encountered this issue when the first column's first two letters were ID (e.g. 'ID_COUNTER'). Renaming the column also helped.

Comment: I encountered this issue with the first column's name as `TABLE` (all caps)